# Exchange 2003 restrict anonymous smtp access only

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003, smtp-auth

On exchange 2003 I want to listen for smtp on port 25 only so that
* anonymous login is only allowed from certain internal IPs
* authenticated login is allowed from everywhere

I can't see how to do this. Any IP filtering seems to affect both anonymous and authenticated login in the same way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately that isn't possible. But you could create a second virtual SMTP server, just not using the same port and local IP. You'd need to either use a different SMTP port instead of 25 or bind the two virtual SMTP servers to different local network cards / IPs.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know that. I'm using port 587 now for authenticated users with the down side of more configuration effort on clients but it has the advantage that I can IP-filter port 25 on the real firewall instead of fooling around on this exchange box.